# Export Dataset from GoogleCloudPlatform to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, export-to-csv, data-analysis

A public data set 'Chicago Taxi' is available at Google Cloud Platform and i need to export it to Amazon S 3. How can i export it?

Comment: I have not done this, but I think these steps are required. Load the dataset into your BigQuery project. Export to Cloud Storage. Then copy from Cloud Storage to S3.

Answer (score -1):

Amiteshwar, if this is a one time task, the below steps will help you. Otherwise, the workflow needs to be designed and an AWS Lambda needs to be created to repeat the program in a fixed interval.  AWS Lambda can be written in Java, NodeJS, etc.

1. Install AWS CLI in your local machine
2. Create a user in AWS with access to the S3 bucket where you want to upload the files.
3. Download the object from Google Cloud using wget linux command.
4. Upload the file into S3 using Rest Api

   PUT / HTTP/1.1

   Host: colorpictures.s3.amazonaws.com

   Content-Length: 0

   Date: Wed, 01 Mar  2006 12:00:00 GMT

   Authorization: authorization string

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html